# How do I create an addition table in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

This should be easy but I can't think of a more elegant way to create an addition table, such as:

```
x <- 1:3
cbind(x + x[1], x + x[2], x + x[3])

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    3    4    5
[3,]    4    5    6
```

I tried various versions of `lapply()` to no avail.

Comment: You are looking for outer. `outer(x, x, `+`)`

Comment: @Sotos, that migt be `outer(1:3, 1:3, "+")`

Comment: @d.b isn't that equivalent to what Sotos said?

Comment: @d.b That is what I wrote. It's just tricky to add backticks in comment

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, I meant the inverted comma around the `+`

Comment: Great! I thought `outer` only did multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `outer` or `sapply` or `expand.grid` (in combination with `rowSums`)

```
x = 1:3
outer(x, x, "+")
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3    4
#[2,]    3    4    5
#[3,]    4    5    6

sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) sapply(seq_along(x), function(j) x[i]+x[j]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3    4
#[2,]    3    4    5
#[3,]    4    5    6

matrix(rowSums(expand.grid(x, x)), ncol = length(x))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3    4
#[2,]    3    4    5
#[3,]    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
m <- diag(length(x))
m[] <- x[col(m)] + x[row(m)]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3    4
#[2,]    3    4    5
#[3,]    4    5    6
```

OR

```
matrix(x,length(x),length(x),byrow = TRUE) + x
```